# java.awt.Robot keyPress slow under macOS

Tags: java, macos, awtrobot

Performance for keyboard simulation under macOS (Java SE 15.0.2) differs heavily from Win10. Typing '100 a' takes on Win10 (openJDK 9.0.4, 14.0.2, 15.0.2) 140ms, Ubuntu VM (openJDK 11.0.9.1) 8200ms and on macOS 11000ms. Results are same on macOS Catalina VM and macOS BigSur on MacBook Pro 2020. Ubuntu test takes 2300ms, if just set focus to text editor direct after start program from console (no effect on macOS).

Inserting `robot.delay(30)` after each keyPress/keyRelease didn't achieved performance gains on macOS. Does anyone can confirm this behavior? It seems like a performance issue in macOS implementation.

When using `javafx.scene.robot.Robot` time on Win10 and MacOS is 30ms.

```
package JavaRobotTest;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sb.append('a');
        }

        typeText(sb.toString());
    }

    private static void typeText(String text) {
        try {
            // Win10 ~140ms, macOS ~11000ms
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            new Thread(() -> {
                // Commenting this line result in Win10 ~15ms, macOS ~11000ms
                robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
                typeTextRobot(robot, text);
            }).start();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void typeTextRobot(Robot robot, String text) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            Integer key = KeyEvent.VK_A;
            try {
                robot.keyPress(key);
                //robot.delay(30);
                robot.keyRelease(key);
                //robot.delay(30);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("DURA ms: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask: What exactly is your question, or is this just an (interesting) observation? Wouldnt it be better to report this to the authors of the code, so they can possibly fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I too see this. The slowness of the `Robot` in sending keystrokes for macOS was introduced with OpenJDK 11. To demonstrate this, I downloaded the OpenJDK 1.8 and 11.x JRE binary zip archives, unpacked them to `~/opt/java/<archive bundle name>` and ran a simple example that does nothing but press and release the `shift` key with a 30ms delay between press/release actions. Below is the output. The 1.8 JVM runs the example in under three seconds. The 11 and greater JVMs take almost 11 seconds to run the same example. For this very reason, for applications that require send key, I compile them with 1.8 compatibility. Very frustrating.

```
smithy@localhost dist % cat ../src/TestRobot.java 
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class TestRobot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            System.out.println("Press enter to continue:");
            press(r, KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, 10);
            System.in.read();
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 101 ; i++) {
                press(r, KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, 10);
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end - start);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println(t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
    private static void press(Robot r, int key, long delay) throws Throwable {
        r.keyPress(key);
        Thread.sleep(delay);
        r.keyRelease(key);
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
smithy@localhost dist % ~/opt/java/jdk8u312-b07/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
smithy@localhost dist % ~/opt/java/jdk8u312-b07/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar TestRobot.jar 
Press enter to continue:

2659
smithy@localhost dist % ~/opt/java/jdk-11.0.18+10-jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10, mixed mode)
smithy@localhost dist % ~/opt/java/jdk-11.0.18+10-jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar TestRobot.jar 
Press enter to continue:

10672
smithy@localhost dist %
```